# Getting actual integer solutions to an equation in Mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to solve an equation using Mathematica but I can't seem to get any actual answers.

Input:

```
Solve[(5*d) + (216*b) == 1, {d, b}, Integers]
```

Output:

```
{{d -> ConditionalExpression[173 + 216 C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers], 
  b -> ConditionalExpression[-4 - 5 C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

I want the output look something like this:

```
{b=123, d=456}
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve gives you **the** solution. If you want **a** solution, change that to FindInstance:

```
FindInstance[(5*d) + (216*b) == 1, {d, b}, Integers]
```

which would be:

```
{{d -> 173, b -> -4}}
```

If you'd like to bring some variety, you can get random solutions directly from solve:

```
Normal @ First @ Solve[(5*d) + (216*b) == 1, {d, b}, Integers] /. 
 C[1] -> RandomInteger[1000]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there is not *one* solution, but in fact a 1-parameter set of solutions (more precisely all the solutions are integer points on a line in (b,d) space).

`Solve` gives you the parametric solution representing the infinite number of solutions.

A way to have a list of small modulus solutions of your system is to do the following

Get the definition of the solution from `Solve`, renaming C[1] as n for convenience, and
explaining to Mathematica that n should be considered an integer.

```
az = Assuming[{n \[Element] Integers}, 
       Simplify[{d, b} /. 
          Solve[(5*d) + (216*b) == 1, {d, b}, Integers] /. {C[1] -> n}]]

{{173 + 216 n, -4 - 5 n}}
```

Then generate solution by varying the parameter's value (We take only the first element of the solution expression, as `Solve` always gives a list even if there is only one solution case).

```
Table[First[az], {n, -10, 10}]

{{-1987, 46}, {-1771, 41}, {-1555, 36}, {-1339, 31}, {-1123, 26}, {-907, 21}, {-691, 16}, {-475, 11}, {-259, 6}, {-43, 1}, {173, -4}, {389, -9}, {605, -14}, {821, -19}, {1037, -24}, {1253, -29}, {1469, -34}, {1685, -39}, {1901, -44}, {2117, -49}, {2333, -54}}
```

This gives you the points nearest to origin which are solutions to your problem. You can plot them with `ListPlot` for instance.